# How can i send and receive a string with a connection between 2 computers from USB port? C#

Tags: c#, usb

I need to send a message from a computer to a USB port and with a cable carry that message to another USB port of another computer and receive it
Can i get some help?

Comment: You can't do it without special hardware between the two computers. Do you have an adapter in mind?

Comment: Scott : Not true.  You can use a USB B cable to USB B cable which is equivalent to a null modem rs232 cable.